# Getting URL when window refreshed doesn't work in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to get the URL of the current window when my web page is refreshed in my Chrome Extension .. here is what I have done :

Part of my manifest.json :

```
  "content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
  "js": ["temp.js"]
}
]
```

My temp.js :

```
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) 
    {      var tabId = tab.id;
           tabUrl = tab.url;
           alert(tabUrl);
    });
```

But this doesn't work.

Please help .. I'm still a beginner x)

Comment: You should read the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: I did but I'm afraid I didn't get all what was there .. so the answer is that I can NOT do that ?

Comment: `chrome.tabs` is only available in the background, send a message with document.location.href instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chrome.tabs` is not available in content scripts. You should create a background script like this:

include this in your manifest.js:

```
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"permissions": [
  "tabs"
]
```

then in background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // This will give you the url if it's changed
    alert(changeInfo.url);
    // Or to always get the tab's url even when it's unchanged
    alert(tab.url);
});
```

[more info](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab)